# complete jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Please, can anyone tell me how to use jqGrid?
I want to do edit, add & delete functionality.
Also I want to show an image in the grid

Please tell me, what can I do, and how can I do?

Comment: You are more likely to get help on this site if you post your attempt at using the plugin and why you think it might not be working.  Nobody is going to show you how to use the plugin when the plugin web site does a great job at it.

Comment: for $50/hr sure. we share our knowledge and expertise here because we all understand the common pains of programming. we do not share our knowledge so you can make money. if you find a specific problem while trying to "delete functionality" then ask that. we will not do your job for you.

Comment: especially when your rep makes it clear that you have contributed nothing to the community :/

Answer (score 2):

All the information you need about jqGrid may be found on the jqGrid sites themselves (as well as stack overflow, of course :)

- [Main jqGrid Page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)
- [jqGrid Documentation Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/)

As far as showing an image in a grid row, [this post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Cold_Fusion_Markup_Language/Q_23977035.html) has a nice summary:

> Return the HTML  element as your grid column's data. Do not use ' or " for the src, it  will not work properly. The field should be like this:

```
<img src=../images/my_image.jpg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#a3").click( function(){
 var su=jQuery("#list5").jqGrid('setRowData',11,  {
 amount:"333.00",tax:"33.00",total:"366.00",note:"<img src='images/user1.gif'/>"});
 if(su)
  alert("Succes. Write custom code to update row in server");
 else
  alert("Can not update"); });
```